# What is needed to get simple Facebook webhook to work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I have created a simple FB webhook app and have subscribed to trigger on feed activity.  I successfully added and tested the user subscription, and clicking the webhook test button test works perfectly.

I have fulfilled all requirements and it is now live, but it does not work on my live FB feed.

I saw a post saying that I needed to obtain "pages_manage_metadata" and "pages_show_list" permissions, and I have been approved for that, but it still won't work despite being in live mode.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you talking about the feed of a page, or a user profile? Does your access token that you used for subscribing, actually include the mentioned permissions?

Comment: I am talking about a feed webhook.  My app is live, and when I test by posting to my live FB feed, no webhook is invoked.
- all permissions are verified and live (pages_show_list, public_profile, pages_manage_metadata, & email)
- my account has been verified using my ID
- the app is subscribed to the "feed" webhook in the app's webhook admin
- testing in the app's webhook admin (test button) is successful at triggering the webhook
- I have authorized the app to access my account via FB login

Comment: Is there *anyone* here who knows about permissions required for get Facebook feed webhooks to work?